# Git: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/SomeBranch'

Tags: git, repository

I am new to git and now the following error occurs:

`fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/heads/SomeBranch' (Conflict through use of capital and small initial letters)
Unexpected end of command stream`

SomeBranch (capitalized!) was actually deleted earlier (local and on remote) and I am working on a local branch someBranch (not capitalized!). Then, I `git add` my local changes and `git commit -m "Some changes" -a`. The error occured while `git push` and also when `git push -u origin someBranch`. someBranch is not yet in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of the entire project (just in case) and then do

```
awk '!/Conflict/' .git/packed-refs > tmp && mv tmp .git/packed-refs
```

Comment: I fixed it by deleting the project (after backup) and re-"git clone <Some url>". Copied the changed files from backup in the new branch later, and then added, commited and pushed. It worked but was rather inconvenient. So will definitely go for your command next time!